# CsvHelper - validate whole row

Tags: c#, csvhelper

### PROBLEM

I have recently started learning more about csvHelper and I need an advice on how to achieve my goal.

I have a CSV file containing some user records (thousands to hundreds of thousands records) and I need to parse the file and validate/process the data. What I need to do is two things:

1. *I need a way to validate whole row while it is being read*

   - *the record contains date range and I need to verify it is a valid range*
   - *If it's not I need to write the offending line to the error file*
2. *one record can also be present multiple times with different date ranges and I need to validate that the ranges don't overlap and if they do, write the WHOLE ORIGINAL LINE to an error file*

What I basically can get by with is a way to preserve the whole original row alongside the parsed data, but the way to verify the whole row while the raw data are still available would be better.

---

### QUESTIONS

**Are there some events/actions hidden somewhere I can use to validate row of data after it was created but before it was added to the collection?**

**If not is there a way to save the whole RAW row into the record so I can verify the row after parsing it AND if it is not valid do what I need with them?**

---

### CODE I HAVE

What I've created is the record class like this:

```
class Record
{  //simplified and omitted fluff for brevity
   string Login
   string Domain
   DateTime? Created
   DateTime? Ended
}
```

and a class map:

```
class RecordMapping<Record>
{    //simplified and omitted fluff for brevity
     public RecordMapping(ConfigurationElement config)
     {
        //..the set up of the mapping...
     }
}
```

and then use them like this:

```
public ProcessFile(...)
{
  ...
  using(var reader = StreamReader(...))
  using(var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
  using(var errorWriter = new StreamWriter(...))
  {
      csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new RadekMapping(config));
      
      //...set up of csvReader configuration...

      try
      {
         var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Record>();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         //..in case of problems...
      }
      ....
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: Check [this out](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/validation/)

Comment: @Magnetron I did. What it does not show is a way to validate against another field. I need to validate one date against another in the same row and I had not found that in the examples or help of csvhelper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this scenario the data might be "valid" from CsvHelper's viewpoint, because it can read the data, but invalid for more complex reasons (like an invalid date range.)

In that case, this might be a simple approach:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Thing> ReadThings(TextReader textReader)
{
    var result = new List<Thing>();
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(textReader))
    {
        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            var thing = csvReader.GetRecord<Thing>();
            if (IsThingValid(thing))
                result.Add(thing);
            else
                LogInvalidThing(thing);

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If what you need to log is the raw text, that would be:

```
LogInvalidRow(csvReader.Context.RawRecord);
```

Another option - perhaps a better one - might be to completely separate the validation from the reading. In other words, just read the records with no validation.

```
var records = csvReaader.GetRecords<Record>();
```

Your reader class returns them without being responsible for determining which are valid
and what to do with them.

Then another class can validate an `IEnumerable<Record>`, returning the valid rows and logging the invalid rows.

That way the logic for validation and logging isn't tied up with the code for reading. It will be easier to test and easier to re-use if you get a collection of `Record` from something other than a CSV file.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to use the first method. The second way is not really possible for me because I need to preserve the unprocessed row and log it in an error file if the row is not valid for logical reasons...

Comment: To get the full "original" row, you can access `csvReader.Context.RawRecord` inside the read loop, before you call `GetRecord()`.

Comment: `csvReader.Context.RawRecord` has been changed to `csvReader.RawRecord` in version 20 of csvhelper

Comment: Not sure if this has changed again recently, but I found it under `csvReader.Parser.RawRecord`.